# Hold button for UK Landline telephone

Tags: telephone

We have retro rotary telephones, and I'd like to make a hold button for the one in my office in the UK.
This is literally a "ye olde rotary phone" (1940s) made from bakelite

I have fairly basic electronics skills but I don't actually know how the phone works, in that sense anyway.

Is this just a case of switching out the circuit to one playing "The girl from Ipenema" or is it more complicated than that?

For example, what is it that keeps the line open if I make an outgoing call? Could I accidentally cut the call or does the line need to go open circuit to do that? What are the voltage limits?

(I would just buy one, but can't find any!)

> [UPDATE]
>
> Some good points have been made in the comments that bear
> highlighting.
>
> When I used to work in a shop repairing computers (about 40 years ago)
> we also sold telephone handsets to the public; the ones with green
> stickers were allowed to be connected to the phone network, the ones
> without - or with red stickers - were not. I'm pretty sure the same or
> similar system exists today, especially with digital exchanges,
> "digital voice" etc.
>
> So, to be clear, nobody should be connecting unauthorised equipment of
> any kind to the telephone network.

Comment: Important: Q1 Is this connected to a "Central Office" telephone exchange line directly, or is it connected as an extension of a small business exchange which in turn has connections to the telephone network proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are phones that work the same as genuine ye olde rotary dial phones, then, a telephone line will be "held" by placing a resistor across the line that draws at least the minimum required by the system.  This will vary by system but I'd guess that a 1k resistor would work. This can be determined experimentally or by asking the system supplier or finding a specification (which probably does exist for most systems).

To place a call on hold (other than leaving the phone 'off hook', "The girl from Ipenema" needs a suitable resistance across the line, and switching must becarried out "make before break".

To make an outgoing call "The girl from Ipenema" must be first removed

Comment: It is literally a "ye olde rotary phone" (1940s) made from bakelite. Thanks for the answer, I'll give that a try!

Comment: @CompanyDroneFromSector7G There may be limitations what kind of devices are allowed to be connected to the interface coming from your phone service provider. The service providers usually forbid connecting anything other than approved equipment to their networks, so wiring a random circuit to a landline may hold you liable for damages.

Comment: @Justme  (1) That's true :-) . (2) That's another question. (3) It seems reasonably likely that this is on a "business system" (PABX in my day and in NZ). If so it's more liable to be whether they are willing to pay for the service call if they break it. (4) Noting that *competently* adding a 1K resistor is very unlikely to hurt much. Incompetently trying to may. (5) I know you know all that :-).

Comment: Thanks @Justme - someone had to say it. I guess I'd better not connect a random circuit to their network then! However, if you have any further tips on how to do this, I'd be grateful :)

Comment: @CompanyDroneFromSector7G  I personally would not let that put me off in the case of a private phone system - the obligations are liable to be non regulatory. || As an ex NZ Telecoms engineer with decades of experience, I'm confident that a 1000 Ohm 5 watt resistor would be extremely unlikely indeed to do any damage. But, never 100% certain. But 99.99% :-).

Answer (score 1):

Telephones are two wire appliances that are grounded only at the exchange end.

A hold-music circuit could go something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHqrul.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The resistor will probably get hot so use a 2W part (or 4 half watt 150 ohm resistors in series etc.)

600 ohms is a guess, measure the current and voltage during a call to get a more precise value.

"Music source" should be at approximately headphone power level.

This is not the best solution it is just the simplest.

There are laws about connecting equipment to the telephone network. Sometimes these are protectionism to stifle competition and innovation, but usually they are there to stop people from connecting dangerous equipment to the network that could harm phone company equipment and employees. If you connect something that behaves very much like a telephone and is safe no-one will care.

Comment: Technical comment only: Switch should be make before break to avoid dropping call. || 5W resistors cheap and preferred.

Comment: Will try this. What is the purpose of the transformer? Is it to reduce/increase the output to a safe/audible level? Is there a rating/spec it should be be? E.g I'm guessing not a mains transformer!

Comment: it's for isolation,  the phone guys are fussy about that.